# Intuitive way to drag UL elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking to get feed back on what would be a good way to implement an intuitive way to drag my UL element. I have made a small JSFiddle that shows my current implementation.

```
$.each($('#area ul'), function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(
        function(){
            var ul_element = $(this);
            ul_element.prepend("<li id='movebar'>Move List</li>");
            $('#movebar').mouseenter(
                function(){
                    $(ul_element).draggable({
                        snap: true,
                        containment:"parent",
                        stop: function(event,ui){

                        }
                    });
                }).mouseleave(
                function(){
                    $(ul_element).draggable("destroy");
                });
                ul_element.sortable({
                    revert:true,
                    containment:"parent",
                    cancel:"#movebar",
                    stop: function(event,ui){

                    }
                 });
            });
    $(this).mouseleave(
        function(){
            $('#movebar').remove();
            $(this).sortable("destroy");
            console.log(false);
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D9yN4/2/

I also am looking for a better solution in selecting a UL element.  Currently my query selects all UL elements in a specific div.  Is there a better way to select individual UL elements?

I also have a limitation on my project where I may not provide an unique ID to a UL element.

Thanks you for any insight.

Comment: `$.each($('#area ul')...` That is just strange...

Comment: Yeah this was a small example. It the main project they could have multiple UL elements. I am also relatively new to JS and JQUERY.

Comment: Most people would write it as `$("#area ul").each( ... )`

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <style>
        #sortable {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 60%;
        }
        #sortable li {
            margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
            padding: 0.4em;
            padding-left: 1.5em;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            height: 18px;
        }
        #sortable li span {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -1.3em;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#sortable").sortable();
            $("#sortable").disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Try this one , its easy way of draggable list and then you can use css code for styling.

Comment: Sorry I was not descriptive enough. I am looking to drag the list as a whole element. This is why I was asking if there is a more efficient way to move the list.  Current implementation has me creating an LI element in the list that hasn't been instantiated with sort able.  This element is an anchor that will allow you to drag the  list inside its parent dive. Take a look at my JSFiddle to get a better idea.